# AWS ubuntu server, web page not loading

Tags: server, apache2, php, amazon-ec2

I'm struggling with something on my AWS ubuntu instance. I'm trying to install MyBB on my server. I've created an RDS database and an EC2 ubuntu instance. On my instance, I've installed apache2 and extracted the files into /var/www/html but whenever I go to my publicip/install/install.php I receive the code for the .php file instead of the installation page of the board.

I've posted a few pictures below, please keep in mind that I'm not that experienced and that I'm learning!:)

Here's my web server:
[view of my web server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMcUt.png)

And here's the wep page:
[view of the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FDxr.png)

Comment: It looks like you didn't set up something to process the PHP.  Did you install `libapache2-mod-php` and then do `sudo a2enmod php` and then restart apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`?

Comment: Thank you man! You've just helped me wrap my head around servers a lot more!:)

Comment: I added my comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You installed `apache2` but you didn't install PHP or the PHP module/processor.

Run the following:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php
sudo a2enmod php
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That should make it work.

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much for your reply and after the comment above pointed out that I didn't have anything to process php. That got me thinking that php, modules and the sql-php extension isn't installed either. I span up another instance and installed the following: Apache, SQL, PHP and modules.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing MySQL**

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

**Installing PHP**

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql

sudo systemctl restart apache2

sudo apt install php-cli
```

**Testing PHP Processing on your Web Server**

```
sudo nano /var/www/your_domain/info.php
```

This will open a blank file. Add the following text, which is valid PHP code, inside the file:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

http://your_domain/info.php
```